# I am trying to make a payment using Braintree but It shows "Cannot determine payment method"

Tags: reactjs, braintree, braintree-sandbox

***Hare is the erros message in console. "Cannot determine payment method".***

> {errors: {…}, params: {…}, message: 'Cannot determine payment
> method.', success: false} errors: {validationErrors: {…},
> errorCollections: {…}} message: "Cannot determine payment method."
> params: {transaction: {…}} success: false [[Prototype]]: Object

Let me tell one thing I have made token properly. Hare I attached  few segment of my code.

const buy = () => {
setData({ loading: true });

```
    let nonce;
    let getNonce = data.instance
        .requestPaymentMethod()
        .then(data => {
          
            nonce = data.nonce;
       
           
            const paymentData = {
                paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
                amount: getTotal(products)
            };

            processPayment(userId, token, paymentData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                   
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            
            setData({ ...data, error: error.message });
        });
};
```

**Hare is the process payment Controller**

```
exports.processPayment = (req, res) => {
    const nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
    const amountFromTheClient = req.body.amount;
    // charge
    const newTransaction = gateway.transaction.sale(
        {
            amount: amountFromTheClient,
            paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
            options: {
                submitForSettlement: true
              }
        },
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(result);
            }
        }
    );
};
```